# Difference not taking the difference of everything?

Tags: openscad

I have two pieces v-piece and i-piece which are joined together with join_pieces().

Afterwards, the combination of those two pieces are meant to be differenced as a whole by two cubes in the piece() function.

The problem is the only piece showing a difference is the i_piece and not the v_piece which even though it is connected, it is left whole with no subtraction. I have removed the difference() line and checked to make sure the cubes are intersecting both pieces and they are. I have tried a union in case the difference was only accepting one object but it appears to not have changed anything.

Any suggestions, or answers to try? Thanks.

```
module join_pieces() {
    union() {
        v_piece();
        translate([0,0,-1*stem_height+INSERT]) {
            i_piece();
        }   
    }
}

module piece() {
    difference() {
        join_pieces();
        rotate([0,0,45]) {
            cube([AIR,V_PIECE_WIDTH*4, RADIUS], center=true);
        }
        rotate([0,0,135]) {
            cube([AIR,V_PIECE_WIDTH*4, RADIUS], center=true);
        }
    }
}

piece();
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you show  the variable definitions and the other functions used by these modules?  I tried running your code with cubes replacing v_piece and i_piece and putting random numbers as the variables.  It seems like your code is correct for what you want to do, running the modified version:

```
module join_pieces() {
    union() {
        translate([-2, 0, 0]){
            #cube([5, 2, 2]);
        }
        translate([0,-2,-1*3+2]) {
            cube([3, 5, 3]);
        }   
    }
}

module piece() {
    difference() {
        join_pieces();
        rotate([0,0,45]) {
            cube([1,3*4, 4], center=true);
        }
        rotate([0,0,135]) {
            cube([1,3*4, 4], center=true);
        }
    }
}

piece();
```

You can see that what you have here is fine.

Have you made sure none of your other functions are missing a semi-colon and used the # to display your difference pieces?

Comment: if you have query ask in comment not as a answer.

Comment: I would if I could, but you can't comment if you don't have 50 reputation.  That's why I also posted a test of his code to show that he has the right functions and they work as he intends.  I also suggested some problems he might be having in other functions.  It was an answer along with an ask for more information.